# Let f in F[x] be irreducible, and let E/F be Galois. Factor f in E[x] to get lower degrees.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $f \in F[x]$ be irreducible, and let $E/F$ be Galois. Then $f$ might factor in $E[x]$ into irreducible factors of smaller degree. Show that all of these have the same degree.

I have a rough idea. That is to use the elements of $Gal(E/F)$ act on the factorization of $f$ in $E[x]$, but I have no idea how exactly... Thanks!

Comment: Hint: if it is Galois it is separable.

Comment: Could you explain in detail? I am really confused about how to use group action always... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f=\Pi_if_i$ in $E[X]$, $Gal(E/F)$ acts on the set of factors $\{f_i,i\in I\}$ which is the disjoint union of orbits of $Gal(E/F)$. You can write $f=\Pi_j g_j$ where $g_j$ is the product of factors of an orbit. $g_j$ has coefficient in $F$. This implies there is one orbit since $f$ is irreducible, the elements of an orbit have the same degree.

Comment: I feel the group action partitions the factors into different cosets in which the factors have the same degree. Is that what you mean? But I don't understand how the group acts on the factors exactly... I am sorry but I don't understand group action very well..... Thank you!

Comment: If $f_i=\sum a_lx^l, s\in Gal(E/F), s(f)=\sum f(a_i)x^l$, now remark that $s(f)=f$ since the coefficients of $f$ are in $F$ and $s(f)=\Pi_is(f_i)$.

Comment: Thanks Group action has been confusing me since I learnt that half a year ago. Thanks a lot a lot!